# How to count based on a criteria in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset like the one in the picture. And I want to group them by count such as in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VXJi.png)tableau:

'Gold' if Total Income is > 5000
'Wood' if Total Income for the year is <= 5000

Number of gold companies: eg. 4
Number of wood companies: eg. 8

Comment: What language? VB?

Comment: The software is Tableau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your final output (granular or not) you may want to try Level of Detail (LOD).

If dataset is something like this:

[image]

For your case, FIXED could be more than enough.

```
if { FIXED [Company] :SUM([Monthly Amount])} >= 5000 then 'Gold' else 'Wood' end
```

Then just drag that field into your worksheet with Compnay field used with COUNT[image]

[Reference for Tableau LOD](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm)

Comment: Any video/book etc you can recommend for understanding of LoDs??

Comment: Could you please acccept the answer in order to make this thread complete?
I'll add some LOD material ASAP

Comment: I've already added the reference to Tableau documentation in the bottom of the answer

Answer (score 0):

A simple **if else** in a calculated field should suffice, like so:

```
IF Total Income is > 5000
THEN 'GOLD'
ELSE Total Income is <= 5000
THEN 'WOOD'
END
```

using this calculated field, you can get the counts directly in the graph.